# How to wire a guards gun?

Tags: gunpoint

I can sometimes wire a guards gun to point at another guard that is on the same level and in sight of each other. But they don't shoot one or the other.

I have had only succeeded once in having a guard shoot the other but cannot reproduce it. What is the process of wiring up a guard to kill another guard?

I cannot seem to wire something to the guards gun, only sometimes a guard to a guard. Sometimes I can't, maybe because they are alerted already.

(I drew a yellow man where my character is)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guns are wired just like any other device in the game. If you draw your line from the gun in question, attempting to fire it will activate the target device, but the gun won't shoot. If you draw the line from a different object to the gun, then activating the device will cause the gun to fire.

Since only one connection can be created between any two devices, getting two guards to shoot one another simply by wiring their guns to one another is impossible.

What you can do instead is wire a light switch to both guards' weapons, and flick it when they're facing each other. Or wire a guard's gun to the light for the room he's in. Now if he notices you, his gun doesn't work, he's distracted fixing it, and can't see you anymore.

Comment: I have attempted to draw a line from the light switch to the gun nearby and it does not link. I posted a screenshot in my OP.

Comment: It seems my issue is a bug. Basically, on restart of the level. I can do one thing, either link to a guards gun or link a guards gun to another guards. Either of those options only works on mission restart and cannot do a second action. I am off to Steam forums to report the bug.

Comment: Wiring weapons requires a lot of energy. Four bars, if I'm not mistaken. Make sure you have at least that many.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget you also need lots of energy for this. Rewiring a gun costs 4 energy.

Gain more energy by buying batteries in the store before your mission, or find batteries within the levels.

Comment: This confused me as well to begin with - the game does not give you a 'not enough energy' notification or anything like that, so it's very easy to miss.

Comment: @Alex same here. I [tweeted](https://twitter.com/naomikyoto/status/513015341455114242) Tom Francis (@GunpointGame) about it. Maybe he'll add a warning message ^.^